# Wrong numeration in toc longer then one page

Tags: table-of-contents, compiling, page-numbering, sharelatex

I tried anything I could find with `\cleardoublepage` and `\newpage` and so on; mostly they use `\addcontentsline`. I don't need to use it as `listof=totoc` already puts it into the toc so even if I use `\addcontentsline` instead I get the same result.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV10,
    ngerman,
    paper=a4, 
    twoside=false,
    titlepage,
    parskip=half,
    listof=totoc,
    bibliography=totoc,
    index=totoc,
    captions=tableheading,
    foottotes=multiple,
    final
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    automark,
    headsepline,
    ilines
]{scrpage2}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

\begin{document} 
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Test}
\label{sec:Test}

Test

\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}

\begin{figure}[H] 
\centering
\caption{Testfig}
\label{fig:testfig}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}
\subsection{Test}
\label{sec:Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example so it can be processed by others so we see the problem, just remove `\include{Inhalt} % .tex-file with many subsubsection to create a 2-page-toc` and add as many `\section{abc}` and `\subsection{xyz}` as you need to show the problem.

Comment: Added it. Hope this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution for me in sharelatex.com:

> Sometimes our compiler doesn't realise it needs to run latex again to get 
>   the table of contents numbering correct. Try adding the following line: 
>   \phantom{\cite{?}} somewhere in your code. This include an invisible 
>   citation which doesn't exist and will trick our compiler into running the 
>   maximum number of times.

Comment: How do I mark the thread as solved?

Comment: By accepting (clicking on the green checkmark) the most helpful answer and upvoting all helpful answers. Self-accepts are possible after 48 (?) hours.

Answer (score 6):

Your example shows correct page entries in the ToC for me. You only described your problem as *"[w]rong numeration in toc longer then one page"*. My guess is that your numbers are off (too low) by one in a two-page ToC (or more general, off by [no. of ToC pages - 1]). The solution is to compile your LaTeX document (at least) *three* times:

- After the first run, the document contains an empty one-page ToC;
- After the second run (having read the auxiliary files from the *first* run), the document contains a ToC with page entries reflecting the ToC length of the first run (i.e., a one-page ToC);
- After the third run (having read the auxiliary files from the *second* run), ToC page entries reflect the correct ToC length.

Comment: I compiled it over and over again.
I actualy got a 3-page-toc, if that matters.

As I said I use sharelatex.com. Got to ask the support if it is a problem with their compiler...

Comment: I contacted the support.
In my thesis the numbers are off by two btw.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem .. table of contents is 3 pages long, but the hyperref links to the pages in the frontmatter (in roman numbers) are not correct and point to the wrong pages. i tried fixing it with `\setcounter{page}{7}` for setting page numbers manually, but it did not work, and also the roman numbers in the table of contents got screwed up this way.

solution was: 
- not using any `\setcounter{page}{7}` (or any other number than 7) for manually setting page numbers in the frontmatter. it will then at least number all pages of the front matter correctly in the header even if the table of contents is longer than one or two pages.

1. Put a `\phantomsection` before each entry.
2. Use a `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents blabla}` to create a TOC entry.
3. Add the chapter of the frontmatter (abstract or acknowledgement via `\include`, `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` or whatever)
4. Use a `\mtcaddchapter` so the minitoc doesnt get out of sync (else they are later placed in wrong chapters).
5. Let a `\cleardoublepage` follow each of these chapters.

It worked fine for me this way, page numbering and hyperrefs are okay.

Example:

```
\phantomsection

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}

\mtcaddchapter

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
```

Repeat this loop for each chapter of the front matter.

In my case, it was the missing `\cleardoublepage` that causes the wrong hyperrefs pointing to pages 2 numbers away because the table of contents was 3 pages long.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may want to take a look at our [starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.