# How do I list a section in table of contents that appears before the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

My institution requires a summary of a report to be on page iii, then the table of contents start on page v (there is other front matter inserted by the publications dept on pages i, ii and iv). I have manually set the page numbers, and manually added the summary to the TOC, but the page number for the summary is listed as v, when it should be iii. Can I specify the page number in the \addcontentsline command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\section*{Summary}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{5}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try reversing the order of the \section and \setcounter commands.

Comment: `\addcontentsline` writes to the `.toc` file at page shipout. To that end it will write the page number of whatever page it is on. Clearly you've placed it on the wrong page (page 5 or v). Place it on the same page as where `Summary` is - either before or after `\section*{Summary}`, depending on how long the Summary is.

Answer (score 0):

John Kormylo's comment didn't quite work, but it helped me refine my search and I found this previous question [Table of Contents incorrect page numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74439/table-of-contents-incorrect-page-numbering)

I was able to fix my problem by moving the `\addcontentsline` before the `\section` line.